# Is there a keyboard shortcut for opening the Visual Studio tab dropdown?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: picture of what I'm talking about]

I'm wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2019 to open this little tab dropdown menu. If it exists, I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is CTRL + ALT + DownArrow assigned by default to the Window.ShowEzMDIFileList command.

Comment: "ShowEzMDIFileList"?!? no wonder, i didn't find that in the keyboard shortcut dialog ;o)